# Retrieve Profile Image

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve user profile image from parse. I have a collection view and I am retrieving all images people posted. I want to show each users profile image in the cell as well. I was using the below code 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.includeKey("pointName")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(question:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            if let allQuestion = question as? [PFObject]
            {
                self.votes = allQuestion
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    // Wire up search bar delegate so that we can react to button selections

    // Resize size of collection view items in grid so that we achieve 3 boxes across

    loadCollectionViewData()
}

/*
==========================================================================================
Ensure data within the collection view is updated when ever it is displayed
==========================================================================================
*/

// Load data into the collectionView when the view appears
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadCollectionViewData()
}

/*
==========================================================================================
Fetch data from the Parse platform
==========================================================================================
*/

func loadCollectionViewData() {
    // Build a parse query object
}

/*
==========================================================================================
UICollectionView protocol required methods
==========================================================================================
*/

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.votes.count
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]





    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

    if let pointer = item["uploader"] as? PFObject {
        cell.userName!.text = item["username"] as? String
        print("username")

    }

    if let profile = item["uploader"] as? PFObject,
        profileImageFile = profile["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
            cell.profileImageView.file = profileImageFile
            cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                }
            }
    }

    if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
    {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
    }

    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        println("Value \(value)") 
        cell.postsImageView.file = value
        cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                cell.postsImageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

However I found out that it sets profile image to the current user and not the user who posted the image. How can I do this? Thank you

UPDATE

so  In parse my post class is [image]

so I know who uploaded it but I don't know how to retrieve the profile image for this specific user.

Comment: But the user you get is correct or not? just only image file is wrong or even the userName is wrong too?

Comment: Thank you for commenting . user name is wrong aswell . It looks like the code is just retrieving my profile and name and not the user who posted the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a pointer that will point to the user who created the object. The profile photo should be in the user class. You then include the pointer in your query and that will return the user data.

Comment: ok I have already used a pointer so that it would point to the user who created the object. Update question.  I don't know how to include it and return the user profile picture

Comment: I am not brilliant with swift, I prefer Obj-c so I will give you the code in Obj-c. In the query statement you would add : [query include:@"pointerName"];   - you should then have access to the user object. I think in swift it would be query.includeKey("pointName")

Comment: Thank you I was doing this all night and still can't find a way to retrieve the image. I have placed the  query.includeKey("pointName")  in the query which is located in the viewDidLoad. I can't return the user data (image). updated question

Comment: no not at all, I can't retrieve profile images and usernames from parse.

Comment: If you haven't had an answer by the time I get home after work - I will copy your code and get the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

okay, this might help you in objective-C

```
PFUser *user = PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; 
[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
 _profileImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"]; 
}];
```

Comment: The posts are in a class and I know which user has posted the pictures. The users are managed in the user class.

Comment: so if user are managed, you don't need to `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, just get `user` directly for saving time.

Comment: You just store `objects` from `UserQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` first, for example in `viewDidLoad`, and call the user class directly. Using `PFImageView` instead of `UIImageView`, and set 
cell.profileImageView.file = (PFFile *) PhotoFile;
[cell.profileImageView loadInBackground];

Comment: Parse kit provides `PFImageView` for convenience. So it might be save time when using it. Hope this could helps.

Comment: ok I have set the class in the view did load as         `let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(question:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in` Where do I set the cell.profileImageView.file = (PFFile *) PhotoFile;  is this swift code? I also changed it to PFImageView. So in the cell it is now     @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: PFImageView!

Comment: ah, I'm not familiar with swift code too much, i'm using objective-C. It could be this if 
let file: PFFile = object["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
            myCell.profilePic.file = file
            myCell.profilePic.loadInBackground()
        }

Comment: your code must change a lot, I can not teach you guy, but you could learn yourseft by taking a look at https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-display-parse-com-images-in-a-table-view-ios-swift-parse-com-f73dd68adb5e, hope it could help.

Comment: ok I think you are misunderstanding the question. I know how to retrieve the images and I am able to retrieve the images from posts class so thats not the problem here. profilePicture is in another class called user.

Comment: okay, this might help you in objective-C
 PFUser *user = PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
   [user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
       _profileImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];
   }];